# ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'buttonpython.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

The error im getting is

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
>   'buttonpython.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you
>   see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
>   circular import.

I am following an older django tutorial because those are literally all i can find and got his error.
Here is the urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.button)
]
```

Settings.py (i included this because i found the buttonpython.urls variable in it):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'buttonpython.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'buttonpython.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import urls.py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def button(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def output(request):
    def trade_spider(max_pages):
        page = 1
        data = ''
        while(page <= max_pages):
                search = 'Ipad'
                url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + search + '&_sacat=0&_pgn=' + str(page)
                src = requests.get(url)
                text = src.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
                for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 's-item__link'}):
                        href = link.get('href')
                        title = link.string
                        if(title == None):
                            title = "Sorry the title was unavailable however you can check the price."
                        price = get_item_price(href)
                        data += href + '\n' + title + '\n' + price + '\n'

                page+=1
        return data

    def get_item_price(item_url):
        src = requests.get(item_url)
        text = src.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
        for item_price in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'notranslate'}):
                price = item_price.string
                return price

    data = trade_spider(1)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data':data})
```

I am stumped any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you import your `urls.py` in your `views.py`?

Comment: try this => `path('', views.button, name="home")`

Comment: Both had no affect

Comment: I am going to upload views.py

Comment: did you add your app name in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: where is your `views.py` located ?

Comment: in the same directory as urls.py and basically everything else except for the home.html

Comment: did you run `django-admin.py startapp app_name` or `python manage.py startapp app_name` before ?

Comment: no, startproject insted of startapp

Comment: remove `from . import urls.py` from views.py and then try.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem said to add it it was originally not there but even then i still got the error

Comment: @fr06t: no I asked if it was there, since that explains the cyclic error.

Comment: oh ok it wasnt there however

Comment: @fr06t _"I am following an older django tutorial because those are literally all i can find"_ Are you saying that the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/), which is the first link in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/), could not be found? Really?...

Comment: i am not very good at following those :D i also meant youtube tutorials

Comment: i will try recreating the project but using startapp instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start project:

```
django-admin.py startproject buttonpython

cd buttonpython
```

start app:

```
django-admin.py startapp app_name
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',

        'app_name',
    ]
```

`app_name/views.py` same as your `views.py` in your question. without import `urls.py`.

urls.py:

```
from app_name import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.button, name="home")
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you have a circular import. For some reason your views.py is importing urls.py. There is no reason to do that, you should remove that import.

Comment: Still no effect